# Mobile database with client-side synchronisation of local databases required

Tags: database, mobile, data-synchronization

I am building a mobile app with the following business requirements:

1. Db to be stored locally on the device for use when disconnected from
   the cloud.
2. A NoSQL type store is required to provide for future changes without requiring complex db rebuild and data migration.
3. Utilises a SQL query language for simple programming.
4. Run on all target platforms - Windows, Android, iOS
5. No central database server - data to be synchronised by matching two local copies of the db file.

I have examined a lot of dbs for mobile and none provide all these features except Couchbase Lite 2.1 Enterprise Edition. The downside of that is that the EE license might be price prohibitive in my use case.
[EDIT: yes the EE license is USD$35K for <= 1000 devices to that option is out for me sadly.]

Are there any other such products out there that someone could point me to?

Comment: How big is your use case? why the community one is not enough?

Comment: @deniswsrosa current use case is tiny, just me. The free version of CBL does not include the local db synchronisation feature.

Comment: @ajaxer What is the expected number of devices?

Comment: @rajagp at this point in time there would be two, my phone and my pc. For wider testing I would ask friends and family so maybe I might get around 10 or 20 devices if I am lucky. Think MVP at the start, with unknown growth once it goes on the various app stores for the public. I am trying to avoid two things - the cost of hosting a central db, & the responsibility of hosting other peoples data.

Answer (score 0):

The client-side synchronization of local databases done by Couchbase Lite is a way to replicate data from one mobile device to another. Though is a limited feature because it works on P2P. Take as an example BitTorrent, the fastest and most effective P2P protocol. It still has flaws, risk of data corruption and partial data loss. A P2P synchronization would only be safe when running between two distinct applications on the same mobile device.

In case both databases are in the same mobile device and managed by the **same** application, it would be much simpler. You could do the synchronization yourself by reading data from one and saving in the other, and dealing with conflicts if needed.

I'm curious, why is it a requirement not to have a central database server? You can fine tune what data is shared and between which users is it shared. Here is how it works:

On server-side user registry, each user is assigned a list of channel names. At the same time, each JSON document added or updated is also linked to a list of channel names. For every pair of user x document with at least one channel name in common, the server allows push/pull replications to occur.

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However as I said,  I am trying to avoid two things - the cost of hosting a central db, & the responsibility of hosting other peoples data.

Comment: @ajaxer Curious - without a central or external db, what do you do if the app or device hosting the app crashes. How do you recover your data ?

Comment: The idea is that the data is private to the user. The data would be backed up to whatever location the user prefers to use for their private data. This is commonly to a cloud location such as OneDrive or Google drive.